# How can make the first value for combo box open?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem with my code when I try to make combo box, because the first value when I look at my apps will be 0, its should be `--PILIH---`

[image]
[image]

Thats the problem and this is my code I take the value from database SQL Server and this is my code:

**for making datatable**

```
 Private tbl_taskpriority As DataTable = clsDataset.CreateTableProjectPriority
 Private tbl_taskstatus As DataTable = clsDataset.CreateTableProjectStatus
```

**for creating table**

```
Public Shared Function CreateTableProjectStatus() As DataTable
        Dim tbl As DataTable = New DataTable
        tbl.Columns.Clear()
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("taskstatus_id", GetType(System.Int64)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("taskstatus_name", GetType(System.String)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("taskstatus_isdisabled", GetType(System.Boolean)))

        tbl.Columns("taskstatus_id").DefaultValue = 0
        tbl.Columns("taskstatus_name").DefaultValue = ""
        tbl.Columns("taskstatus_isdisabled").DefaultValue = 0

        Return tbl
    End Function
```

**and this is on design**

```
cProjectstatus_id.Name = "projectstatus_id"
        cProjectstatus_id.HeaderText = "ID Project Status"
        cProjectstatus_id.DataPropertyName = "projectstatus_id"
        cProjectstatus_id.DataSource = Me.tbl_taskstatus2
        cProjectstatus_id.ValueMember = "taskstatus_id"
        cProjectstatus_id.DisplayMember = "taskstatus_name"
        cProjectstatus_id.Width = 100
        cProjectstatus_id.Visible = True
        cProjectstatus_id.ReadOnly = False
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2005

Comment: Set `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1` in the Form_Load event, if it is the second item in the combobox that you wish to have visible.

Comment: That is nice code but it doesn't show us how you filled the combos.

Comment: You're showing the ComboBox af a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, bound to the `Me.tbl_taskstatus2` DataTable, which you're not showing here (you have posted code about `tbl_taskpriority` and `tbl_taskstatus`). This appears to be working properly. Post the code related to the ComboBox controls.

Comment: I would suggest that you set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`.